# Amazon Connect: Agent without CCP?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have the following requirement for a call center: at night calls needs to be routed to the mobile phone of the on-call engineer. This engineer needs to first hear a message and enter his personal PIN.

As I see it I have 2 options:

a) I can route the call to an agent's mobile phone (deskphone option) but this only seems possible if the agent is logged in to the Contact Control Panel. I could then use a whisper flow to ask the engineer for his PIN.

b) I can route the call directly to an external number (transfer to phone number) but then I can no longer control that part of the call so I cannot interact with the engineer to ask for his PIN.

I would prefer option a but can this be done without the agent being logged in to CCP?

Alternatively, for option b, is there a way I can setup a flow for external calls?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure a contract flow to first check staffing. to see if the agent is logged in; if not send the caller to the on call tech cell phone (may need lambda and dynamodb).  Configuring a call flow to route to an external number is easy enough but once your transfer to an external number you lose control, recording etc.   I generally handles this use case by having the caller leave a VMmessage for the on call tech.  The message causes the system to send an SMS (lambda PinPoint) to the tech who calls in hears the message and is connected via call back.  We also create what old PBX techs would know as "DISA" where mobile workers call in, enter pin, then anchor in the system and make out bound calls.  In this way the techs cell is masked, the call is recorded and archived for reporting. -DrVoIP

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The main reason they want the agent to identify by entering a PIN is to make sure that the call does not go to the agent's voicemail, I think Amazon Connect is not able to differentiate between a call being answered by the agent or by their voicemail so according to Amazon Connect the call setup succeeded and the call is with the agent even if it's their voicemail. Do you know of a way to work around that?